# Why is $C_G(A)$ a normal subgroup of $B$ in this context?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, exact-sequence

Let's consider the group extension $G$ s.t.
$$1 \to A \to G \to B \to 1$$ where $A$ and $B$ are finite, non-abelian and simple groups. Let $C_G(A)$ be the centralizer of $A$. Since $A$ is normal, $C_G(A)$ is normal as well. Furthermore, the intersection of a subgroup of a group and its centralizer is just the center of the subgroup, and we know that non-abelian simple groups are centerless. So $A\cap C_G(A) = 1$ and $AC_G(A) = A\times C_G(A)$.

From here how can we conclude that $C_G(A)$ is isomorphic (as a group) to a normal subgroup of $B$? For one, $B$ might not be (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $G$! Second, I don't see why $C_G(A)$ should be normal in $B$. Moreover, $B$ might not even be a complement of $A$ unless $G$ is a split extension (cf. [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/5535)).

I'm trying to understand the claim made in the second paragraph of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3669229).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the image of $AC_G(A)$ in $B$ under the map $G\to B$. The kernel of the map is $A$. So the image is isomorphic to
$$\frac{AC_G(A)}{A} \cong \frac{C_G(A)}{C_{G}(A)\cap A} = \frac{C_G(A)}{\{e\}} \cong C_G(A).$$
Thus, there is a subgroup of $B$ that is isomorphic to $C_G(A)$.

Since the map $G\to B$ is surjective, it maps normal subgroups of $G$ to normal subgroups of $B$. Since $AC_G(A)$ is the product of two normal subgroups of $G$, it is normal in $G$. So its image is normal in $B$. But the image is isomorphic to $C_G(A)$. So $B$ contains a normal subgroup that is isomorphic to $C_G(A)$.

Since $B$ is assumed to be simple, this means $C_G(A)$ is either trivial or isomorphic to $B$. In the latter case, it turns out that $G$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $B$ that intersects $A$ trivially, and by order considerations you get $G=A\times C_G(A)\cong A\times B$ and the extensions is split.

Note that the claim is not that $C_G(A)$ *itself* is a subgroup of $B$, but rather that it is *isomorphic* to a subgroup of $B$.

Comment: Why is the kernel of the map $A$? How have you defined the homomorphism?

Comment: @Triskelion: The map comes from the short exact sequence $1\to A\to G\to B\to 1$ that describes the extension. That means that the kernel of the arrow $G\to B$ is **precisely** the image of the arrow $A\to G$; that is, the kernel is $A$. The homomorphism is *given* by the fact that you have an extension.

Comment: @Triskelion: Saying “the extension $1\to A\to G\to B\to 1$” literally means: “$G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ isomorphic to $A$, and $G/N$ is isomorphic to $B$; the map $A\to G$ maps $A$ isomorphically to $N$, and the map $G\to B$ maps $G$ to $G/N$ and then isomorphically to $B$.” This is usually shortened to assume the map $A\to G$ is an embedding, and the map $G\to B$ to be the canonical projection.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now and I will accept your answer. Just another minor query: even if $A$ and $C_G(A)$ had non-trivial intersection (but were both normal, like here), would $AC_G(A)$ still be normal in $G$? (I mean in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_group_subsets#Product_of_subgroups_with_non-trivial_intersection) sense, i.e., product of subgroups with non-trivial intersection.) Why or why not?

Comment: Oh, I guess I found the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991008. Nevermind!

Comment: Guess I won’t get a barrage of “anonymous” emails telling me off tonight, then....